# Synergy Linux Keyboard '@' Problem

Tags: linux, fedora, synergy

Im using Fedora 10 with Synergy from Windows 7

When ever i use my keyboard through synergy and type `@` i get the `Omega` Sign

Any ideas, or someone had similar problems?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had problems with @, <, and >, so I did the following:

Code:

> xmodmap -e "keycode 53 = x X greater greater greater greater"
>   xmodmap -e "keycode 52 = z Z less less less less"
>   xmodmap -e "keycode 24 = q Q at at at at"

Which solved those three... though I have no idea why the problem occurs in the first place.

Comment: My keyboard on the linux machine works fine, Its on Synergy that it fails.

Comment: @Systech I just added your work around to our bug tracker.

Comment: @nbolton Any chance of an actual fix instead of this workaround?

Comment: Boy.. How you worked that out I'll never know, I thank you. My wife thanks you!!!

Comment: I lose it when I reset the machine though :(

Answer (score 4):

This is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/detail?id=62), and we're working on it right now. There are several work arounds however, so if you take a peek at that issue, you may find something. If you have a Google account, you can *star* the issue to get a notification when it's fixed.

Comment: Nick - is there a new link for that bug in the tracker please?

Comment: here is the link to this issue on the new tracker: https://github.com/symless/synergy/issues/62

Answer (score 1):

Create a file ~/.Xmodmap and add the following to it:

```
keycode 53 = x X greater greater greater greater
keycode 52 = z Z less less less less
keycode 24 = q Q at at at at
```

You can activate it straight away with:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

I believe this will activate automatically when you reboot - but I hardly ever reboot, so haven't tested this.

Thanks (and +1) to Systech's answer for the contents of the file, and thanks to [this page](http://dev-loki.blogspot.com/2006/04/mapping-unsupported-keys-with-xmodmap.html) for instructions on how to make it persist across reboots.

Answer (score 0):

pobably a keycode translation problem. Have a look at the synergy configuration. You should use the same language settings as locally

Comment: i cant find the synergy config on fedora any ideas?

Comment: There are two possible locations for the synergy server config file, either `~/.synergy.conf` or `/etc/synergy.conf` - however, this will not help fix the issue, since it's a software bug and not a config problem.

Answer (score 0):

locate synergy.conf, its probably in /etc

Comment: The synergy server config is also located at `~/.synergy.conf` (but modifying the config is unlikely fix the problem).